# continuity of derivatives(space and time) of the solutions to heat IVP

Tags: functions, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider the heat initial value problem on 
$\mathbb{R}$:
    \begin{align*}\tag{1}
  \begin{cases}
   \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,x)&=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}(t,x) \qquad t>0, x\in\mathbb{R}, \\
  u(0,x)&=f(x),\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}
  \end{cases} 
 \end{align*}
We know that $u$ is continuous on $[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}$. Then
we proved that $u$ is a solution to (1) in classical sense by showing all its required derivatives exists and $u$ itself satisfies (1). In particular we use a continuity argument similar to Evans PDE, see for instance
p.64-65 in
[enter link description here](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~vvksrini/1d-fund-heat.pdf)

Now, my question is, how can I show continuity for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2}$, and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$.

I think I just need to modify Evans' continuity argument for $u$, but I am not sure how.To be more specific, what is the general strategy to prove continuity of 
derivatives of solution? Given we know the solution itself is continuous.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the explicitly known Green's function $G(x-y,t)$, $u(x,t)=\int
dyG(x-y,t)u(y,0)$ to investigate these properties.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? A bit too general I'm sorry but I'm  not sure what u mean

Answer (score 0):

The Green's function is usually obtained by Fourier transforming. In the
square integrable case the procedure is rather elegant. Suppose $u\in L^{2}(%
\mathbb{R},dx)$. Then $\partial _{x}^{2}$ extends to a self-adjoint operator
$-p^{2}$, $p^{2}\geqslant 0$. The solution is
\begin{equation*}
u(x,t)=\exp [-p^{2}t]u(x,0)
\end{equation*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
&<&x|\exp [-p^{2}t]|y>=\int dp<x|p>\exp [-p^{2}t]<p|y> \\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi }\int dp\exp [i(x-y)p]\exp [-p^{2}t]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int dp\exp [iap]\exp [-p^{2}t] &=&\int dp\exp [-p^{2}t+iap]=\int dp\exp
[-t(p^{2}-i\frac{a}{t}p)] \\
&=&\int dp\exp [-t\{(p-i\frac{a}{2t})^{2}+(\frac{a}{2t})^{2}\}] \\
&=&\exp [-\frac{a^{2}}{2t}]\int dp\exp [-tp^{2}]=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{t}}\exp [-
\frac{a^{2}}{2t}]
\end{eqnarray*}
Obviously the same Green's function is obtained in other situations.

Comment: Thanks. I will come back to questions...

Comment: What you had there is correct. But my question is to show continuity for $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial u^2}{\partial x^2}$, and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$.

Comment: Since $u(x,t)=∫dyG(x−y,t)u(y,0)$ and we know $G$ and $u(y,0)$ these properties can be checked directly. In the $L{^2}$-case we have $u(t)$ is (strongly) continuous in $t$ as an $L{^2}$-function. The spatial derivatives of $u(t)$ need not exist but do if they exist for $u(0)$.